# localhost mysql not connecting to java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection, localhost

I am quite new to Java and MySQL. I had followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCqW5XwtJxY&t=557s which allows me to connect localhost mysql to Java but it seems like not working for my code and project. This is my code.

***DPAT.java***

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    DBConnection connect = new DBConnection();
    connect.getData();
}
```

***DBConnection.java***

```
package dpat;
import java.sql.*;
public class DBConnection {
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public DBConnection()
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:1234/databasetest","root","");
        st = con.createStatement();
                    }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("erro:" + ex);
        }
    }

    public void getData()
    {
        try{
           String query = "select * from tabletest";
           rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Records from databases");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                int ID = rs.getInt("ID");
                String name = rs.getString("Name");
                int age = rs.getInt("Age");

                System.out.println(" Name: " + name + " ID " + ID + " age " + age );
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex + "error");
        }
    }
}
```

May I know what is wrong with my code? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: What exception are you getting? Also a tip: do not publish passwords in internet.

Comment: *it seems like not working* What doesn't work? Why? What were you expecting? What is happening instead? Is there any error? If yes, please paste the full stack trace in the question, along with the answer to all previous questions.

Comment: The port is set as 1234, and not just an example?

Comment: The default port of MySQL is port 3306, not 1234. Doing things like `System.out.println(ex + "error");` is rarely helpful, if anything use logging, or at minimum `ex.printStackTrace()`, which provides information which you should have included when posting this question.

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks for reminding. There is nothing shows in my output even exception. The output I expected is the results from my database table

Comment: @BackSlash Maybe the question is too ambiguous, Thanks for reminding

Comment: @LanceToth it is the localhost, just an example. Thanks

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Is 3306 port still applies in localhost? Anyhow, I will give a try. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Port 3306 is the default unless explicitly configured otherwise.